# How to stop excel from truncating length of field output

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have some fairly complex string manipulation functions for cells which I then further concatenate

```
B1=A1
B2=B1&";"&A2
B3=B2&";"&A3
etc
```

the problem is when I copy the final B e.g. B100 the output is truncated.  I need the concatenation so I can use the final output as a series of queries to run for mysql. Is there anyway to ask Excel to not truncate or a workaround so I can get all the the B queries stacked into `Query1;Query2;...;QueryN`

Comment: Examine the `Specifications and Limits` for your version of Excel to see how much can be contained in a single cell.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmcalculation says "Length of formula contents" is 8.192 chars, not sure if that is input or output. I did check the concatenated output in word it is 32676 with spaces, eyeball estimate is I need 4* that amount.

Comment: Can you do the string concatenation inside MySQL?

Comment: @user3649739 Well, with Excel, you won't be able to do that.  You should be able to accomplish your task in VBA -- The string data type can contain 2^31 characters.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I made life easy on myself and just made each row end with ; then copied the whole column and done.